# How to add flash display movieclip to starling sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mask, movieclip, starling-framework

I use starling framework, and I want to add flash.display.MovieClip to starling sprite?

I want to use mask on starling sprite, but I nothing found how to do this. That's why I want to use flash.diplay.MovieClip's mask method.

Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could flatten the movieclip by drawing a 'normal' movieclip with mask to a Bitmap and use that as child inside the starling movieclip.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

But, this Sprite object - which I want to mask - is contains many childs, including buttons. If I flatten this Sprite object, then the buttons is lost their properties ( I cannot click on them ).

Is there a possible way to mask Sprite object without loosing any child properties?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't if you use flatten method it will remove all its properties. It will make it as simple image. Use flatten method only for single image which doesn't have any child properties or which does not have any functionality. For these cases only flatten method will work.